# C segmentation fault in interfacing with accelerometer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi, accelerometer

I am interfacing the Raspberry Pi with an accelerometer using the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include "LSM9DS0.h"

void readBlock(uint8_t command, uint8_t size, uint8_t *data);
void selectDevice(int file, int addr);
void readACC(int  *a);
void writeAccReg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value);
void enableIMU();
int file;

void  readBlock(uint8_t command, uint8_t size, uint8_t *data)
{
    int result = i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(file, command, size, data);
    if (result != size)
    {
        printf("Failed to read block from I2C.");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void selectDevice(int file, int addr)
{
        if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
         printf("Failed to select I2C device.");
        }
}

void readACC(int  *a)
{
        printf("entered readACC");
        uint8_t block[6];
        selectDevice(file,ACC_ADDRESS);
        readBlock(0x80 | OUT_X_L_A, sizeof(block), block);

        *a = (int16_t)(block[0] | block[1] << 8);
        *(a+1) = (int16_t)(block[2] | block[3] << 8);
        *(a+2) = (int16_t)(block[4] | block[5] << 8);        

        printf("X axis: %4.2f, Y axis: %4.2f, Z axis: %4.2f", a, a+1, a+2);
}

void writeAccReg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value)
{
    selectDevice(file,ACC_ADDRESS);
  int result = i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, reg, value);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        printf ("Failed to write byte to I2C Acc.");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void enableIMU()
{

    __u16 block[I2C_SMBUS_BLOCK_MAX];

        int res, bus,  size;


        char filename[20];
        sprintf(filename, "/dev/i2c-%d", 1);
        file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
        if (file<0) {
        printf("Unable to open I2C bus!");
                exit(1);
        }

        // Enable accelerometer.
        writeAccReg(CTRL_REG1_XM, 0b10010111); //  z,y,x axis enabled, continuos update,  100Hz data rate
        writeAccReg(CTRL_REG2_XM, 0b00100000); // +/- 16G full scale
        printf("Accelerometer is enabled\n");
}

int main(){
enableIMU();
printf("fine\n");
int *a;
readAcc(a);  
return 0; 
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
 Accelerometer is enabled 
 fine 
 Segmentation fault
```

Based on the output, the function enableIMU is working fine, the output also shows "fine" which is right before entering readACC, but I never enter readACC because "entered readACC" doesn't get printed. Instead, I get a segmentation fault.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong here? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Suggest you add `\n` to the end of all your debug print strings. The reason is because `printf` is line buffered by default and will not output until it sees a newline. Which often causes confusion during debugging as it may appear some code hasn't executed when it really has.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}',  Never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when writing the prototype for a function, where that function does not take any parameters, use `void` between the parens so the compiler does not think that the function can take any number of parameters.  I.E. rather than: `void enableIMU();`   use: `void enableIMU( void );`  Note: it is not necessary (nor desirable) to use the `void` in the actual function body/signature

Comment: the posted code, when the call to `selectDevice()` fails, continues to an instruction to try and read from that device.  probably not what you want.  Suggest that the function: `selectDevice()` calls `exit()` when the ioctl() fails

Comment: the`function: `readACC()` seems to have a problem.  float values are 4 bytes each on the raspberry PI, so storing 2 bytes into the value will not produce a valid float value. And the parameter `int *a`  will not properly convert to float values.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code has several unused variables, each of which will raise a compiler warning.

Comment: the function: `ioctl()` is normally found in `sys/ioctl.h` suggest inserting the statement: `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`

Comment: Have you ever tried to compile the posted code?  I think not.  there is a world of difference between `readAcc()` and `readACC()`.   Capitalization counts in the `C` language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is:

```
int *a;
readAcc(a); 

…

*a = (int16_t)(block[0] | block[1] << 8);
```

In the first line, you declare a pointer to an `int`. This pointer points *somewhere*, since it is not initialized. Then, in the last line, you write to this *somewhere* in memory.

Instead, you should write this:

```
int16_t a[3];
readAcc(a);
```

That way, you define the storage where the function `readAcc` can write to. The parameter to the `readAcc` function should not be a pointer to `int`, but a pointer to `int16_t`, since you use it as such.

Inside `readAcc`, you can then write:

```
a[0] = …;
a[1] = …;
a[2] = …;
```

Instead of the array, you could also define a `struct xyz { int16_t x, y, z; }`, which describes more accurately what the code does.

I would write it like this:

```
struct xyz {
    int16_t x, y, z;
};

void readACC(struct xyz *coord)
{
    printf("entered readACC\n");
    selectDevice(file, ACC_ADDRESS);

    uint8_t block[6];
    readBlock(0x80 | OUT_X_L_A, sizeof(block), block);

    coord->x = (int16_t)(block[0] | block[1] << 8);
    coord->y = (int16_t)(block[2] | block[3] << 8);
    coord->z = (int16_t)(block[4] | block[5] << 8);        

    printf("X axis: %4.2f, Y axis: %4.2f, Z axis: %4.2f\n", 
        coord->x / 256.0, coord->y / 256.0, coord->z / 256.0);
}
```

- I defined the `struct xyz` to make the code self-explaining.
- I moved the `selectDevice` call above the `block` declaration, since the `block` is not needed for that.
- I replaced the `a` parameter with a better name, `coord`, which has an appropriate data type.
- I corrected the arguments to the `printf` call to match the `%f` conversion specifier. (I hope the factor 256.0 is correct.) When you try to print an `int` using `%f`, the *behavior is undefined* (which is the worst thing that can happen in a C program).
- I added newlines to the end of the `printf` format strings.